# How do I import my own custom swift file into a project?

Tags: swift, xcode, import

I have a swift file with some extensions and helper functions that I like to use in all of my projects. It is platform-agnostic.

Right now, I've been pasting a separate copy of the file into all of my projects whenever I need to use it. This is obviously not ideal because if I need to modify the file, then I have to update all of the copies floating around in each of my projects.

**How to I import a file from outside my project into my project without making a separate copy?**

In Python, you could simply write `import [module name]` at the top of your file and it would import that module into your script.

Here's a link to the file in case anyone's interested.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1keOZ98BQS6ErqTn_xXl10RWrc7WNJdFw/view?usp=sharing

Comment: You can do this using Swift Packages and a remote repo.  https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/creating_a_standalone_swift_package_with_xcode

Comment: How about creating a private cocoa pod and using that.

Comment: How do I do that?